# Moving through mutiple iFrames using XPath & C#

Tags: c#, html, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to get a data element out of a table, which is nested within two iframes.  The frames appear as:

```
<iframe id="appContent" frameborder="0" name="appContentFrame" src="/controller.aspx" style="height: 0px; width: 1319px;">
       //....
            <iframe id="childFrame" frameborder="0" src="javascript:"";" onload="AjaxDocument.registerFrames('childFrame');" name="childFrame">
```

I am trying to select both of the frames by using:

```
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame("appContent");
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame("childFrame");
```

The calls worked the first time I used them, however when I call them a second time, after I load a new webpage, they can not be found.  I used these same calls earlier in the program where I was inputting data on another webpage with the same named iframes.  Is it possible the reason why I can not call them again is because both set of calls are within the same scope of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason is because you are not switching back to the parent. When you are done working inside first `iframe` do a `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()` which will take you back to the previous frame and do the same for the upper layer of `iframe` once more.

**Edit**

Finding correct API doc on C# is painful. However, these are the most concise definitions of two important methods used for switching frames.

```
driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
```

> Select the parent frame of the currently selected frame.

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

> Switches to the element that currently has the focus, or the body element

Refer to [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/bcb1720c6f7f1e98d97dae15eadb576f65eb1094/dotnet/src/webdriver/ITargetLocator.cs)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Should i be making a call to `DefaultContent()` for each iframe I enter?  Or is one call enough to bring me back to the default state of the page? -- regardless, I pass where I was being halted, so thank you for the answer! +1

Comment: Correct API documentation is supplied as a .chm file with every instance of the .NET bindings downloaded via the [Selenium project download location](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). It is freshly generated when the project is released. The online hosted version of the documentation is not updated as often, because generating the API documentation for .NET requires touching every single file in the documentation site, which runs into the thousands of files.

Comment: @JimEvans Thank you for that info.  I had no idea!